# Delete Some Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic

Given an array that consist of $n$ integers $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_n$. Now I want to delete some(possible none, but not all) elements from the array, such that arithmetical mean of all remaining numbers will as big as possible.

Find number of ways to delete numbers.

EXAMPLE : Let $n=4$ and array be $1~2~1~2$

Then here answer will be $3$.

Comment: Delete all the numbers except the biggest in the array since finding the arithmetical mean of the biggest with something smaller will lower the result.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on @John's observation, suppose the largest number appears $m$ times.  We definitely delete all other numbers.  Of the $m$ copies of the largest number, we delete any subset we like, except all of them.  Hence there are $2^m-1$ possible additional numbers to delete.  In the example given, $m=2$ so there are $2^2-1=3$ ways to achieve the goal.